# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 error is being received and cannot confirm why

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I understand that this error message indicates that I am trying to access a particular element in an array via index which is not present, or it is an invalid element trying to access outside of the length in a String. However, I have not been able to confirm where exactly this is occurring in my code with the information provided from error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at Week3.luis_ramirez_GamesReport.readWrite(luis_ramirez_GamesReport.java:63)
    at Week3.luis_ramirez_GamesReport.main(luis_ramirez_GamesReport.java:30)
```

I have reviewed previous questions posted about this but my code formats don't seem similar to others that have been posted. I have attempted to change the order of my output but since the desired output is already printing, I stopped doing so. I have also attempted to change line

```
String[] ints_only = Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 1, record.length);
```

to a value of 0 instead of 1.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class luis_ramirez_GamesReport {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        {
            File fileName = new File("/Users/luisramirez/eclipse-workspace/GameScores.txt");
              readWrite(fileName);
              addGamer(fileName, "Jimmy", "189", "190", "197", "199", "198", "193", "199", "199", "188", "196");
              readWrite2(fileName);}
          }
        private static void readWrite(File fileName) throws IOException {
            

        if (fileName.exists())
        {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String csvSplitBy = ",";
            int recordCount = 0;
            //String number ="167";
            //int result = Integer.parseInt(number);
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Games Report");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Gamer    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10     Total");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
        String[] record = line.split(csvSplitBy);
        String[] ints_only = Arrays.copyOfRange(record, 1, record.length);
        List<Integer> recordAsInts = Arrays.stream(ints_only)
            .map(str -> str.strip())
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        int sum = recordAsInts.stream().reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0);
        System.out.println(record[0] + "\t"
            + record[1] + (record[1].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[2] + (record[2].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[3] + (record[3].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[4] + (record[4].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[5] + (record[5].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[6] + (record[6].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[7] + (record[7].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[8] + (record[8].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[9] + (record[9].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + record[10] + (record[10].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")
            + sum);
            recordCount++;
                
        }
        
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("# of Gamers: %d%n",recordCount);
        System.out.println("Top Gamer: ");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            br.close();
        }
```

Here is a link to an image of my output:

[image: Output]

Here is line 30: `readWrite(fileName);`

Here is line 63:             `+ record[1] + (record[1].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, how many elements do you expect `record` to contain, after doing `String[] record = line.split(csvSplitBy);`? Why? Did you *check* that? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Which line is 63? `+ record[1] + (record[1].length() > 7 ? "\t" : "\t")`?

Comment: Hey @tgdavies, yes that is the line 63. I have edited the post with line 63 and line 30. Thank you for reaching out.

Comment: Hey @KarlKnechtel, I am reading the documentation you provided. Thank you for providing them. I am working on answering your question as well.

Comment: "_Index 1 out of bounds for length 1_" - This means you have an array with only one element. Since Java arrays are zeroth indexed, that means that this only element is on index 0 and you were trying to access index 1 which is out of bounds (outside this array). If you understand what that means, change the title of your post with the specific doubt you have.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked fine, actually i changed the path of the folder
and added some other lines to make others players.

i think your problem is that you are not using the absolute path

[image]